# Can an Excel VBA dictionary be used to call a function?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a large number of functions that I need to call which each have the same arguments and I'd like to be able to centralize them to avoid unwieldy blocks of code. Obviously I could use a wrapper function to just call all the others, but I don't always call all of them. My next thought is that I could place the functions in a list or dictionary and call them from there, much like in Python:

```
def foo():
    return "foo"

myDict = { "foo": foo }

myDict["foo"]()
```

Returns `foo`

Is something similar possible in VBA? If so, what is the simplest way of doing it?

Comment: Likely the best you could do is to use `Application.Run(myDict("foo"))` but that's not really a pattern which translates well to VBA, which doesn't really have a concept of function pointers.

Comment: There is a `CallByName` function which can be used to call any function by its string representation. So for example you can do: `CallByName("foo")` which will in turn call the function named "foo". Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a really straight forward way of doing this, however, it can be done using a combo of a list and the `CallByName` function.

You can make a list which contains all the function names as strings:

```
myFunctions = ( "foo" "bar" "baz" )
```

You can then iterate over the array to call the functions:

```
For Each functionName in myFunctions
    CallByName Sheet1, functionName, VbMethod, listOfArguments
Next functionName
```

Functions can be filtered out with `If` statements

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are inside objects/Classes then you can call them by name directly.
The below code works inside SHEET1 because it's an object.
It will not work in a MODULE as that is outside the capabilities of CALLBYNAME function.

So you can store the Names in the Key of the dictionary and then just use the key (no function pointer is needed)

```
Public Sub Something(arg1 As String)
    MsgBox arg1
End Sub

Public Sub test()
    CallByName Sheet1, "Something", VbMethod, "data 1"
End Sub
```